# How to set the shipping price depend on quantity or the order cost WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

How to make the price of shipping is free of charge if

- The requested quantity are more than 2 pieces.
- Or the order cost more than $500.

Answer (score 1):

For 2 > items try this.
Put this code in functions.php of your child-theme files.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_free_shipping_is_available', 
'free_shipping_two_items', 10, 3 );
 function free_shipping_two_items( $is_available, $package, $shipping_method ) 
 {
 $item_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

 if ( $item_count == 1 ) {
    $is_available = false;
 } elseif ($item_count > 2) {
    $is_available = true;
 }
 return $is_available;
 }
```

For price free shipping - this is major function of woocommerce shipping settings. After you set your free shipping settings use this article here to hide all other shipping methods.

[Link](https://flexibleshipping.com/woocommerce-free-shipping-over-amount/)